# Electrodeposition using Ionic liquids

Tags: electrochemistry

I haven't found to many research papers yet, but would it be possible to electroplate nickle-aluminide onto a niobium alloy using an ionic liquid? I know certain industries are already using this combination for rockets or thruster according to my research so far. I'm looking in to using something like 1-ethyl-3 methylimidazolum bis (trifluoromethyl-sofonyl)mide or [EMIM] [TG2N] as the ionic liquid in the electroplating to act as the solvent. With what I know so far, should this be a plausible process for electroplating a niobium alloy?

Comment: Please do not duplicate posts! Remove this question or https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/176834/electrodeposition-using-an-ionic-liquid . If you wish to make a change, **edit** the question you've submitted.

Answer (score 3):

Nickel-aluminum alloys can indeed be deposited from solutions of nickel chloride in an organic chloroaluminate salt. As one example, [Ali and Nishikata [1]](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-0728(01)00607-6) describe an electrodeposition process on platinum and mild steel. From this reference:

> Electrodeposition of aluminum–nickel intermetallic compounds (particularly Ni3Al) has been carried out onto platinum and mild steel cathodes from a 2:1 (mole ratio) aluminum(III) chloride-N-(n-butyl)pyridinium chloride (BPC) molten bath saturated with nickel(II) chloride at room temperature. A single phase of Al–Ni alloy is difficult to obtain by controlled-potential and controlled-current methods; however, it can be obtained by pulse current plating. ...

For a broader eeview, consult [Oriňáková et al.[2]](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10800-006-9162-7).

**References**

1. Ali, Muhammad & Nishikata, Atshushi & Tsuru, Tooru. (2001). "Electrodeposition of Al–Ni intermetallic compounds from aluminum chloride-N-(n-butyl)pyridinium chloride room temperature molten salt". *Journal of Electroanalytical Chemistry*. **513**. 111-118. 10.1016/S0022-0728(01)00607-6.
2. Oriňáková, Renáta & Morovska Turonova, Andrea & Kladeková, Daniela & Gálová, Miriam & Smith, Roger. (2006). "Recent developments in the electrodeposition of nickel and some nickel-based alloys_. *Journal of Applied Electrochemistry*. **36**. 957-972. 10.1007/s10800-006-9162-7.